# Undocumented exceptions in the .NET Framework

Tags: .net, exception, getfiles, undocumented-behavior

Once again, I'm struggling to understand an undocumented behavior of the method `GetFiles` in `System.IO.Directory` (this is going to make me crazy). While running some routine tests, I found out to my surprise that a call to this method was throwing an exception of type `NotSupportedException`, which is not mentioned in the [MSDN page about `GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx), in the list where the other exceptions are.

For example, this call in C#:

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"XY:");
```

throws a `NotSupportedException`. My first impression was that the documentation page is missing a piece of information, but after thinking again, I'm not really sure. I mean I've always been assuming that all exceptions I need to care about when using the .NET Framework classes are well-known and documented.
For example, I never put a handler for a `FileNotFoundException` when I'm joining strings because I don't expect this exception to occur there.

Is my assumption wrong? Should I expect at least certain exceptions to potentially pop out of anywhere like an `OutOfMemoryException`? Any statement I need to read?

Comment: In `.NET 4.0` i have got `Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory 'XY:' not found.`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan I'm running Windows 7 x64, and I'm getting a `NotSupportedException` in .NET 4.0 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly some types of exceptions that can occur at any time without warning (a good example would be the classic `StackOverflowException`).

I 'd call this particular case a documentation bug though. The documentation for `NotSupportedException` does mention the `System.IO` classes in general, and it also says that the `HRESULT` value `COR_E_NOTSUPPORTED` translates to said exception type. I 'm not sure if it's reasonable to ask that *every* possible error result from PInvoked code be clearly listed as a possible exception type, but that's what seems to be happening here.